# Drupal 6 Multilingual Site - permission to translate by node type?

Tags: drupal, translation, profile

I have translations enabled for page and profile (I am using the Content Profile module).

When I give authenticated users the 'translate content' permission, they get a Translate tab on their profile, but they see the "Translate" tab on all pages as well. Users need to be able to create a translated version of their profile, but definitely not of random site content - only content editors can do that. There does not seems to be a way to configure Drupal so that access to the content translation interface is controlled by node type. Since I need translations of all content, I can't just turn it off for pages.

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, 2 minutes after posting this I found [this rather crude fix](http://drupal.org/node/924878). Still waiting for better ideas.